# sunspot_rails gem - " Errno:: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect (2)) "

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, rubygems

I use gem sunspot_rails https://github.com/outoftime/sunspot
I did everything according to the instructions on http://railscasts.com/episodes/278-search-with-sunspot, but get an error

> Errno:: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect (2)):
>   app/controllers/books_controller.rb: 7: in `index '

code from **books_controller.rb**

```
  def index
    @search = Book.search do
      fulltext params[:search]
    end
    @books = @search.results
  end
```

what it can be?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Have you started the Solr server?

```
rake sunspot:solr:start
```

If not than start the solr server first

And If yes than try

```
rake sunspot:solr:run
```

Hope this will help .

Comment: yeap, I ran rake sunspot:solr:start
When I try to run rake _sunspot:solr:run_ I had:

No such file or directory - java -Djetty.port=8982 -Dsolr.data.dir=/home/sergey/Sites/bookoid/solr/data/development -Dsolr.solr.home=/home/sergey/Sites/bookoid/solr -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/tmp/logging.properties20111007-11769-pt9x4a -jar start.jar

Comment: @TiSer It looks like you may not have java installed. Try installing Java and see if that helps.

Comment: nice awnser, this caused me some headace! tx!

Answer (score 9):

Just configure the rake task with the test environment:

```
rake sunspot:solr:run RAILS_ENV=test
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your rails app is looking for the solr server on the correct port.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Java Runtime Environment already installed.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```