# Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am developing a spree application ,I recently removed and reinstalled ruby  1.9.3, now whenever I try **rails s** on terminal I get the following error :

> /home/swapnil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `initialize': Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need configure your Database connection in your database.yml and launch your SQL server with this configuration

Comment: What if it only happens some of the time? For instance, on my local machine I can log in as a registered user and use the app just fine, but I get the `Connection refused - connect(2)` when I attempt to register a new user. Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 8):

Try this one : rake sunspot:solr:start
Look at this issue.I guess it may be helpful to you.
[sunspot_rails gem - " Errno:: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect (2)) "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687343/sunspot-rails-gem-errno-econnrefused-connection-refused-connect-2)